# AWS cli and boto versions - Multiple versions and aws cli not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, boto, botocore

We have a Jenkins instance with aws cli installs as well as a pinned boto version.  This has lead to aws not resolving in the instance

```
# aws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 58, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 69, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.assumerole import register_assume_role_provider
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/customizations/assumerole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from botocore.credentials import JSONFileCache
```

Running aws with its full path works

```
# /usr/local/aws/bin/aws
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
```

Updating the path in the environment variable doesnt resolve the issue.

Any ideas

Comment: To give a bit of context, we have chef run on this instance with cookbooks calling the aws cli.  Since these cookbooks do not need to define the aws cli path since typically aws resolves to the cli as default, chef is now failing on this specific instance

Answer (score 0):

My issue was saved in 2 ways.
I removed the chef cookbook calling aws cli

AND

to resolve future issues, i updated the path but this time i appended the start of the path (not the end) since 2 versions of AWScli were installed

I didnt realise that the path variable is read from start to finish, it was reading the path environment variable for the older AWS cli rather than the newer one which was causing me the issue, moving the new awscli path to the start of the path variable solved it